# Removal of binding offset when submitting digital version of document

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry, printing

I'm writing my dissertation in LaTeX, and we're required to submit a paper copy and a PDF copy. For the paper copy, I'm using:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}
```

...so that it can be printed double-sided and bound with the correct margins.

But for the PDF copy, would you comment out the `bindingoffset` so that the document is "symmetrical"?

Forgetting about what my organisation's rules might be, are there any guidelines for creating both a digital and a paper copy?

Comment: Personally, I'd not only remove the binding offset, but also (most of) the margins, so that the resulting pdf is more ebook-reader-friendly.  And maybe I'd made another, screen-friendly version with landscape orientation.

Comment: Using Ghostscript to crop all pages of the PDF should be a good way of turning the PDF meant for printing into the digital version you want without so much white space. Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183479/cropping-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-9-01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below minimal. Un-comment the `\setboolean{ForPrinting}` line to set it for printing. It optimizes the document for screen printing. You may need to do some minor adjustments to suit your geometry for the actual paper publication.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}[2006/05/05]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{ForPrinting}

%% UNCOMMENT the next line for a PRINT-OPTIMIZED VERSION of the text %%
%\setboolean{ForPrinting}{true}

%% Initialize values to ForPrinting=false
\newcommand{\Margins}{hmarginratio=1:1}     % Symmetric margins
\newcommand{\HLinkColor}{blue}              % Hyperlink color
\newcommand{\PDFPageLayout}{SinglePage}

%% Re-set if ForPrinting=true
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ForPrinting}}{%
  \renewcommand{\Margins}{hmarginratio=2:3} % Asymmetric margins
  \renewcommand{\HLinkColor}{black}         % Hyperlink color
  \renewcommand{\PDFPageLayout}{TwoPageRight}
  }{% If ForPrinting=false, don't skip to recto
  \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}
}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{ForPrinting}}{%
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}%
  \setlength{\paperheight}{11in}%
  \usepackage[body={5.5in,7.33in},\Margins]{geometry}[2002/07/08]
}{%
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{6in}%
  \setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}%
  \usepackage[body={5.5in,7.33in},\Margins,includeheadfoot]{geometry}[2002/07/08]
}
\usepackage[pdftex,
  hyperfootnotes=false,
  pdftitle={Your book title here},
  pdfauthor={Yiannis Lazarides},
  pdfkeywords={maths, table of equations},
  pdfstartview=Fit,    % default value
  pdfstartpage=1,      % default value
  pdfpagemode=UseNone, % default value
  bookmarks=true,      % default value
  linktocpage=false,   % default value
  pdfpagelayout=\PDFPageLayout,
  pdfdisplaydoctitle,
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=0,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=\HLinkColor]{hyperref}[2007/02/07]

% Re-crop screen-formatted version, accommodating wide displays
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ForPrinting}}
  {}
  {\hypersetup{pdfpagescrop= 0 30 612 765}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

A short-cut is to download [calibre-ebooks](http://calibre-ebook.com/) and do automatic conversions using it. You can reformat the PDF for all sort of readers.

Comment: What is the advantage of insisting on using (at least) such an old version of `geometry`?  Were features you are using only introduced then..?

Comment: @jon This is from an old publication of mine. Should work with current versions as well. Also I used `ifthen`, there are better ways to do it now. The perils of cut and paste. If you fix it will you please edit my post and update it?

Comment: My comment was only that it did not seem like there was an advantage to loading packages of at least such and such a date since the features you were using were (probably, but I am not sure) older than those dates.  That said, I think the answer is fine for the question: easy to understand, and easy to implement.