# \href in printable version

Tags: urls, printing, href

I'm ultimating my thesis and I need two different version: one printable and one digital. The thesis contains some `\href`s that of course are lost when I print the document. I would like to know if there is some automatic way to convert all the hyperefs to something that would work also when printed. I was thinking to a footnote or a collections of URLS at the end of the document, but I'm open to anything that requires little effort.

Taking inspiration from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47510/removal-of-binding-offset-when-submitting-digital-version-of-document), I would like to differentiate between the printable and non printable version with just one command.
What are all commands to be used for optimise the printable version? And for the digital one?

```
\setboolean{ForPrinting}{true}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{ForPrinting}}{%
  % Commands for printing
}{%
  % Commands for digital
}
```

Do you have any suggestion? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply redefine `\href` command in *true block*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newboolean{ForPrinting}
\setboolean{ForPrinting}{true}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{ForPrinting}}{%
  \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{#1}}
}{}

\begin{document}

\href{https://example.com}{hyperlink}

\end{document}
```

When `ForPrinting` is `true`, then `\href` simply prints the text and adds a footnote, when it's `false`, nothing is changed and hyperlink is clickable.

[image]

Comment: Simple and effective, thanks!